# How to get the previous URL in Form message

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7, contact-form

I am working on a WordPress site, where I have created a `Contact Form`.

So whenever someone clicks to `apply` for a job advert it takes them to a `Contact Form`

Example site - https://www.inext.se/job/solution-architect/

Application Contact Form - https://www.inext.se/job-apply-form/?id=6770

Now I am trying to get is the `previous URL subject/title` or the `previous URL`.

In JavaScript, I know it is possible to get it by -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(document.referrer);
</script>
```

But I didn't find anywhere how to get in a form `mail` `message body`.

I have tried to use -

```
[_url]
[_post_name]
[_post_title]
```

But this gives me the form URL which is useless for me.

Do anyone know any solution!

Answer (score -1):

I think your best shot is to add a parameter in the URL from the page you are leaving. Doing that will bring the user to the new page with an extra GET parameter that can be your title/url.

With Cf7 you have a very ugly way to do that which is described here: https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

As long as your cf7 form item name equals the GET parameter name, you are good to go. The bad thing about this is that you have no pre-processing power and you need to pass values directly in the URL, w/o any encode (that's from what i know at least)