# Dynamically Add a WordPress Post Title in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on a WordPress site, where there is a Job section. Where a user can apply for a job, that is why I have created a `Contact Form` to receive the application with Applicant's Name, email, address & CV's.

Now When an applicant clicks to apply for a `Job advert` it takes them to a `Contact Form`

Example site - https://www.inext.se/job/solution-architect/

Application Contact Form - https://www.inext.se/job-apply-form/?id=6770

Now I am trying to get is the Job/Position `Title` as the Subject of `Contact Form`.

[image]

So right now I am receiving the Applicant name as a Subject, But instead of this, I want to use the `Title` of the Job as a Subject.

Which can be found in the `class="info_item"` `<p> Solution Architect</p>` as the form message section. As an example- here the title is `Solution Architect` which means the form subject also should be the same.

I have searched almost everywhere and almost everything and I didn't find any solution how I can fetch that Information into the `form message` section!

Do anyone knows any solution how I can use that class Info as the Subject of the `form message` section of the `Contact Form`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous URL in Form message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426854/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-form-message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code -

Put below code in your function.php file

```
function form_title_function(){
  if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['id'];
    $title = get_the_title($post_id); 
    echo "<h2>".$title."</h2>";
  }    
}
add_shortcode('form_title', 'form_title_function');
```

And use the below shortcode to the contact form subject

```
[form_title]
```